# Cannot run VC++ program without debugging

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2003

I can run with debugging and I can run in release mode but I cannot run without debugging. I am pretty sure I messed up the configuration in visual studio somewhere but I am not sure. The computer was frozen I may have inadvertently clicked something. It normally works. Does anybody have any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT:
The program works with F5. It also works when I put the configuration to Release and run the executable. However Ctrl + F5 does not work, and the executable it creates does not work either.

I just get an error saying windows is looking for a solution and then this:
[image]

I even tried getting the entire solution from source safe with the same results...

EDIT 2:
After following the windbg advice given to me below, I arrived at this error:

```
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for mfc71d.dll -
```

Comment: Can you be more clear. Are you trying to say that your program works when an Ctrl+F5 is given and does not work in F5 along.

Comment: When the err pops up see the details, most common reason is FileNotFoundException, your app needs a dll that couldn't be found

Comment: @Jani, it seems you were correct.. why would it find the dll in "Debug" but not "Start without debugging"

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have some undefined behavior in your program, such as uninitialized variables. In debugging mode this doesn't cause a crash because the debugging versions do things like initialize memory for you and don't do any sort of optimization.

Check for wild pointer mistakes, and check for uninitialized memory problems. And turn up the warning level on the C++ compiler to level 4 (the highest practical level). That should help you catch these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: thanks for your response. Given the edits above... do you think that I can rule out uninitialized variables as the problem? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the program crashed.  It also looks like that GUI is pointing you at a crash dump.  Here's how to inspect the dump.

Download "[Debugging tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx)" from Microsoft.  Install it.

Then run, from a command prompt:

```
> cd \Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64) [or possibly without (x64)]
> windbg -z C:\users\ntsoiasue\appdata\local\temp\wer3f91.tmp.mdmp
```

When windbg starts, it will give you a command prompt...

Type the following into that command prompt:

```
> .sympath+ [path to your VS output folder (eg. "Release").
             That is, somewhere with a .pdb file for your binary]
> .reload -f [name of your binary]
> k
```

This will give you a stack trace of the crash.

By the way.  Windbg is a pretty good tool and worth getting to know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I followed the instructions that you specified and in the trace I have this error:

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for mfc71d.dll -

I am googling it as we speak but wanted to keep you guys updated in case you had any insight. Thanks!!

Comment: @ntsue mfc71d is the C library.  Specifically the debug version.  It's saying it can't find the PDB for it.  What does the full output of "k" say?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a full rebuild?  Maybe manually removing all intermediate and output files?

Comment: thanks for the response. Yeah I did a rebuild... even rebooted the machine.. no luck

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me also. I had to do a full uninstall of vc++. Reboot your machine and install again.It worked for me.